# Use aliases in SQL - I am having trouble displaying idshipments numbers collectively. It only shows ID 1200 but I want it to show 1200,1201,and more

Tags: sql, alias

```
SELECT 
    shipment.idShipment, customer.companyname, product.manufacturer, 
    product.productname, 
    shipment.scantag, product.priceperunit, shipment.Quantity, 
    (product.priceperunit * shipment.Quantity) AS Ordertotal
FROM
    shipment, customer, product
ORDER BY 
    idShipment ASC
```

The first row is `idshipment` but only displays 1200 but I want it to show 1200, 1201, 1202, and so fourth

The relationship is on the table shipment. There's `customer_idcustomer`, `product_idproduct` and `employee_employeeid` in the `shipment` table

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: what relationship is between  shipment, customer and  product.

Comment: you are doing a cartesian join, probably not what you want. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm

Comment: You need to define the relationships between those 3 tables.  As Gordon suggested, using JOINs between the 3 tables is a better approach.  Eg. from shipment INNER JOIN customer ON shipment.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer.  (Although, I don't know if idCustomer is the field for a customer's ID - you will know from the data structure what the correct fields are to relate the "shipment" table to "customer" and "product")

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fields, in your "shipment" table, that you are saying reference the "customer" and "product" tables

```
SELECT shipment.idShipment, customer.companyname, product.manufacturer, product.productname, 
shipment.scantag, product.priceperunit, shipment.Quantity, (product.priceperunit * shipment.Quantity)
as Ordertotal
from shipment
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.idCustomer = shipment.customer_idCustomer
INNER JOIN product ON product.idProduct = shipment.product_idProduct
order by shipment.idShipment ASC
```

When you do this sort of SELECT across multiple tables, you are (in most cases) going to need to use JOINs to establish the relationships between the tables so that you get the corresponding information for each record (eg. only display the name of the customer that's related to the shipment).  Otherwise, without the JOIN relationships, you're just telling SQL to cross-query every record from every table